# Объектно ориентованое программирование с Perl

Tags: ооп, perl

Здраствуйте, у меня возникла такая проблема с Perl, как создание объектно ориентированного программирования; где можно найти видео уроки именно по объектно ориентированному программированию на Perl?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, перл вполне себе ооп язык, по одному запросу в гугле "перл ооп" вылезет валом ссылок. Кроме того в документации по перл есть очень много всего: [Perl Programming Documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, посмотрел, но мнение остается прежним.

Comment: Может стоит тогда ещё разок прочитать теорию об ООП, дабы освежить?

Comment: Посмотрев ответы, и статьи еще раз, признаю, в perl можно программировать оо, не смотря на то, что при создании данного языка изначально никто особо и не задумывался об ооп. Но это уже в какой-то мере извращение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, на ссылки есть на что взглянуть!

Comment: Павел, ещё раз повторюсь. Прочтите теорию по ООП. Вы рассуждаете, как типичный начинающий java/c# программист, для которого важны ключевые слова "class", "virtual", "protected" и прочие. ООП это не ключевые слова, это идеология или парадигма, как будет угодно. В JavaScript нет указанных ключевых слов, он вообще мультипарадигменный именно потому, что средствами языка позволяет реализовать разные методологии. Так же и Perl. Да и вообще любой другой. Не обязательно иметь ключевые слова, важно иметь возможность реализовать парадигму. Почитайте теорию, это полезно.

Comment: (2 Павел). Дополню, что те реализации, которые есть в тех же java/c#/c++, это одни из возможных реализаций парадигмы ООП. Но это не означает, то другие невозможны или являются извращением.

Comment: спасибо, теорию обязательно посмотрю. о javascript сразу не подумал. Плюсую. Всем спасибо за содержательные ответы. Мне только кажется мы слегка ушли от изначального вопроса о видеоуроках))

Answer (score 3):

Если в языке реализована инкапсуляция, наследование и полиморфизм, он является объектно ориентированным и позволяет осуществлять ООП. Perl очень даже подходит под эти критерии.

Что такое "псевдо-ООП"? Не могли бы Вы дать определение этому термину?

Comment: В perl, конечно, можно программировать оо - blessed hashes, Moose итд. в помощь. Но ооп концепт не был изначально реализован в perl. По сути нет поддержки со стороны языка, но есть реализация.

Comment: Что означает фраза "нет поддержки со стороны языка"? Как может существовать реализация без поддержки?

Тот факт что Perl может быть использован в структурном программировании и изначально только там и использовался, не означает что он не имеет поддержки ООП. 

Кстати появилась эта поддержка только в Perl 5, в 1995ом году.

Comment: Согласен, посмотрите комментарии к ответу от @KneLL, думаю, мне стоит более интенсивно поработать с Perl, + посмотреть теорию. Спасибо за Ваш ответ. =)

Answer (score 2):

Ничего себе - "не является объектно-ориентированным". Еще как является! Очень простая, но очень мощная ОО-модель. Все обычные парадигмы ОО реализованы, плюс есть множество "фич", сама мысль о которых в классических ОО-языках даже не может возникнуть.

- Изменение структуры существующих (например, "библиотечных") классов (`sub NotMyPkg::xxx {...}`).
- Динамическое изменение структуры объекта (списка атрибутов).
- Динамическое изменение структуры класса (списка методов) (манипуляции с хэшем `%Pkg::`, в т.ч. и локальные, т.е. с потерей изменений послы выхода из блока кода).
- Динамическое изменение класса объекта (повторный вызов `bless` с другим именем класса).
- Динамическое произвольное изменение списка родительских классов (манипуляции с массивом `@ISA`).
- "Ловушка" для обработки вызовов несуществующих методов (`sub AUTOLOAD`).
- Код инициализации и финализации класса.
- Динамическое создание классов (с помощью `eval`).

Comment: Да, все это есть, и даже описано по ссылке, которую я дал. Тем не менее, это по сути лишь псевдо оо. реализация, довольно муторная и неудобная.

Answer (score 2):

Речь идет о том, что ООП не инкапсулировано в язык, а надстроено над ним. И все хвосты, в виде явных ссылок, постоянно торчат.
Таким же образом можно над любым языком с реализованным аппаратом ссылок, например С, надстроить псевдо-ООП.

Comment: В том то и дело, что оо приходиться реализовывать с бубном и надстройками, что порой не очень удобно.

Answer (score 2):

Родная Perl реализация:

- [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html)
- [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html)
- [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html)
- [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0202/lib/Moose.pm)

Если Moose кажется слишком "жирным", то http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/Moo/.

Можно почитать книжку [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/), где в т.ч. рассмотрен Moose.